# AVFoundation - Video file size is increased when I overlay sticker to the video

Tags: avfoundation, overlay, filesize

AVFoundation is increasing video file size when I overlay image to the video. I have set output filetype as mp4. Sometimes video file size is not increased, but sometimes it is increased around 40 MB. Is there any possibility to decrease file size always?

Comment: I use `AVAssetWriter` for export rather than `AVAssetExportSession` to avoid size increase

Answer (score 0):

You should check the way you put stickers to your video. Is it an animation (images of sticker's movement)  or just an image. If it is just a single image, for example before start the export session you could do something like this:

```
    let parentLayer = CALayer()
    let videoLayer = CALayer()
    let overlayLayer = CALayer()
    let stickerLayer = CALayer()

    parentLayer.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: renderSize)
    videoLayer.frame = parentLayer.frame
    stickerLayer.frame = parentLayer.frame
    overlayLayer.frame = parentLayer.bounds
    //Add the image inside of stickerLayer(in this case its from a screen shot of UIView, you can change to your custom UIImage
    stickerLayer.contents = self.stickerView.asImage().cgImage
    parentLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)
    parentLayer.addSublayer(stickerLayer)
    parentLayer.addSublayer(overlayLayer)

    //create composition
    let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    videoComposition.renderSize = CGSize(width: renderSize.width, height: renderSize.height)
    videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 30)
    videoComposition.renderScale = 1.0

    //finally add layers with animationTool
    videoComposition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayers: [videoLayer], in: parentLayer)
```

Comment: It's just an image. AnimationTool is increasing video size sometimes, not always.